# Aggregate Measures in Dax

Tags: dax

The context of the problem at hand is the utilization of a Tabular model which contains two tables, namely 'Base' and 'Kpis'. The 'Base' table contains all the data, while the 'Kpis' table comprises all the measures in relation to the 'Base' table. The issue being faced is the aggregation of specific measures within the 'Kpis' table, namely 'k1', 'k2', and 'k3', on the columns present in the 'Base' table, namely 'c1', 'c2', and 'c3', using the DAX function 'SUMMARIZECOLUMNS'. The primary concern is that some measures are being duplicated across rows, resulting in a deviation from the desired outcome of summing the rows to each total. The objective is to aggregate the measures based on the columns in the 'Base' table. I could I do this using a query with dax-studio?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Simply make sure that when you are creating a measure in the `Kpis` framework and you want to filter for some column in `Base` within the measure, you should use the function `FILTER`.